# Change Order of Filters in Hikashop

Tags: joomla-3.x, hikashop

Pretty much self-explanatory. The `Order` field in the filters menu in the backend is greyed out and I cannot find another way to change the order of the filters.

It seems to me I'm missing something because reordering filters is quite essential to a lot of sites with many filters.

My filters:

[image]

As you can see, "Volltextsuche" is at position 13. I want it to be the first though but can't change the order because it's greyed out.

Please enlighten me :)

Comment: it would be recommended to contact in Hikashop forum and more details would be appreciated

Comment: @Ruchika I would love to give more detail, I just don't know what else to say about the issue o.o. Concerning the forum, I thought I'd get some life in here because I really prefer SE over the HikaShop forum

Comment: you can provide some screenshot for better understanding of everyone

Comment: @Ruchika good point, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: glad to hear this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never worked on HikaShop before, but this appears to me as a classic issue of inactive ordering fields until you click on `'Order'` column header, in your case `'Reihenfolge'`.

I'll bet you any money that when you click on it, it will become active sorting filter (on your screenshot field `'Id'` is active at the moment), and columns for ordering will become active, thus allowing you to set the order you want.

It is a weird issue, and gets easily overlooked thus making unaware users go bezerk.

Comment: ... are you serious. That's some weird design choice right there. Thanks a lot for your help, you won your money, take the reputation ;D

Comment: ...rrright... I was laughing too when I learned that trick for the first time, trust me... :-)   

But than again, it works all around in Joomla since v3... :-(